# Why does this SQLite query select all dates, even those outside of the criteria?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am running sqlite to select data between two ranges for a sales report. To select the data from between two dates I use the following statement:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "11/1/2011" AND "11/8/2011";
```

This statement grabs all the dates even those outside the criteria. The date format you see entered is in the same format that I get back. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Just a quick related tip. If you can always use yyyy/MM/dd as a format. It'll stop the pesky regional differences problems which might be your problem.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

SQLite requires dates to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  Since the data in your database and the string in your query isn't in that format, it is probably treating your "dates" as strings.

Comment: After changing the date format I ran the query again as
'SELECT date FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "2011-11-1" AND "2011-11-2";'
and got back results for 2011-11-16 :/

Comment: That's the 10th and the 20th of the month.  Try `BETWEEN '2011-11-01' AND '2011-11-02'`.

Comment: If you are dealing with Android SQLite ,make sure its yyyy in small letters

Comment: SQLite treats dates as strings regardless of the format they're in. The reson using YYYY-MM-DD works is because the text sort order is the same as the chronological sort order. Any padded numeric format with bigger fields before smaller fields will work.

Answer (score 41):

Change your data to that formats to use [sqlite datetime formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD

SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-01-11' AND '2011-08-11'
```

Comment: The right idea, but given that the data coming back is also in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, I suspect that this still won't work as the data in his database will be treated as strings rather than dates.

Comment: @EricPetroelje Yes - but once you match the format in the DB to the format in the query, it would work.  It looks like it was edited later to include what the updated query should be once the DB is updated - though the query needs single quotes instead of double-quotes.

Answer (score 19):

One more way to select between dates in SQLite is to use the powerful **strftime** function:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) BETWEEN "11-01-2011" AND "11-08-2011"
```

These are equivalent according to https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html:

```
date(...)

strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ...)
```

but if you want more choice, you have it.

Comment: The quotes should be single quotes, but otherwise query should work.

Comment: This still won't work, `strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '11/1/2011')` returns null because that's not a format it takes. In addition, if you did `BETWEEN '11-01-2011' AND '12-01-2011' you're not going to get things from November 2011, you'll get things from many different years. The string `'11-01-9999'` is between them too.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE julianday(substr(date,7)||'-'||substr(date,4,2)||'-'||substr(date,1,2)) BETWEEN julianday('2011-01-11') AND julianday('2011-08-11')
```

Note that I use the format: `dd/mm/yyyy`.
If you use `d/m/yyyy`, Change in `substr()`.

Comment: Great use of splicing!  Voted up.  Note that you don't need to use `julianday()`, though, and using that assumes your date is in UTC because `julianday()` calculates against a GMT-based time, so you can end up with including dates you don't want, and including dates that you do, if your dates are in local time.  You should be able to just do `SELECT *
FROM TableName WHERE substr(date,7)||'-'||substr(date,4,2)||'-'||substr(date,1,2) BETWEEN '2011-01-11' AND '2011-08-11'` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can cast your string to Date format with **date** function. Even the date is stored as TEXT in the DB.
Like this (the most workable variant):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE date(date) 
BETWEEN date('2011-01-11') AND date('2011-08-11')
```

Comment: I think the problem with this solution is that your not indicating the date format of the TEXT (e.g. if the date string is stored as 'MM/DD/YYYY').  I tried this approach and it does not work for me, and I think that's the reason.

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. In SQLite the date functions returns a date as text like `2011-01-11`, so calling `date('2011-01-11)` returns the input. Using `SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-01-11' and '2011-08-11';` will have the same effect. Regardless, calling it with the format in OP (`date('11/1/2011')`) will not work as that is not a format it accepts.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite does not have a concept of dates. It only knows them as text. When you do this in SQLite you're actually doing string comparisons. You can read more from the [official documentation](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#sort_order).

> When two TEXT values are compared an appropriate collating sequence is used to determine the result.

Any numeric (i.e., not using words like 'May') format for dates that is padded and in order from biggest field to smallest field will work. "2021-05-07" (May 7th) comes before "2021-05-09" (May 9th). So if you use "yyyy-mm-dd" format then you'll be set. "yyyy/mm/dd" and "yyyymmdd" work just fine too. (For a better phrasing on "sortable" date formats check out [RFC 3339 section 5.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339#section-5.1).)

A reason to use "yyyy-mm-dd" format is because that's the format that SQLite's builtin `date` uses.

Answer (score 2):

Special thanks to [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781965/jeff) and [vapcguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1181535/vapcguy) your interactivity is really encouraging.

Here is a more complex statement that is useful when the length between '/' is unknown::

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE julianday(
    substr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), '/')+1)
||'-'||
    case when length(
    substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1, instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1),'/')-1)
    )=2
    then
    substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1, instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), '/')-1)
    else
    '0'||substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1, instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), '/')-1)
    end
||'-'||
    case when length(substr(date,1, instr(date, '/')-1 )) =2
    then substr(date,1, instr(date, '/')-1 )
    else
    '0'||substr(date,1, instr(date, '/')-1 )
    end
) BETWEEN julianday('2015-03-14') AND julianday('2015-03-16')
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, and gotta hand it to you for your ability to do substrings.  My same comment about `julianday()` from the other post still applies, though.  This is basically the same answer as the other except you put in conditional logic to add in leading zeros for single digit days and months.  Probably should have been added to the other answer, or replaced it with this edit. Upvoted, since it is more correct, though.

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable in the Where Condition and parse both dates using 'BETWEEN':

```
SELECT * FROM emp_master
```

-> if you have date formate like dd/mm/yyyy simple then,

```
   WHERE joined_date BETWEEN '01/03/2021' AND '01/09/2021';
```

-> and if you have date formate like yyyy/mm/dd  then,

```
   WHERE joined_date BETWEEN '2021/03/01' AND '2021/09/01';
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are preparing data for some report. Then the whole ordeal will look similar to this.

```
--add column with date in ISO 8601 
ALTER TABLE sometable ADD COLUMN DateInISO8601;

--update the date from US date to ISO8601 date 
UPDATE sometable 
SET DateInISO8601 = substr([DateInUSformat],length([DateInUSformat])+1, -4) 
  || '-' || 
  substr('00' || [DateInUSformat],instr('00' || [DateInUSformat],'/'),-2)  
  || '-' || 
  substr('00' || rtrim(substr([DateInUSformat],instr([DateInUSformat],'/')+1,2),'/'),-2,2);

SELECT DateInISO8601 
FROM sometable 
WHERE DateInISO8601 BETWEEN '2022-02-02' AND '2022-02-22';
```

You can of course do all that on the fly, but if you have the choice -- don't. Use the ISO date by default and convert it on the way in and out to SQLite DB.