# how to retrieve date between two dates in sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

OrderDate is Date type field in my table with formate dd/MM/yy and this is field belongs to all records in the table.

I need to get only those orders filter by two dates like **O.Order_Date  between '01/11/12' and '15/11/12'** But it select also select those records that does not belongs to November and this year.

[image: Here is the Result of query]

Could anyone plz guide me how to get correct data between two dates.

Comment: I think that the problem is with the date format, try using this ``YYYY-MM-DD``. Take a look to this [page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query**

```
insert into test (t) select '2012-01-15';

insert into test (t) select '2012-11-16';

select * from test where t between '2012-01-01' and '2012-02-01';
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4a8d0/20)

Comment: as can be seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates    you may have to massage your old data

Comment: Thanks but I have Date field in my table and that is filled like dd/MM/yy how do make it in YYYY/MM/DD formate only in the query for comparison bcoz I can't set my field in specific format now that has spread in all over project.

Comment: copy that table to another one let's call it B. now in B do an update stmt to change the date for every row so it is in the format of YYYY-MM-DD keeping in mind that say 1 would be 01. then run a test

Comment: you need to change your data first do you need help with that

Comment: what i am saying and that other link suggests is that if you do not save it exactly as YYYY-MM-DD then sqlite saves it as a string and not a date. so in that case trying to retrieve date ranges will fail

Answer (score 2):

You should try also operation > and <.

For example:
where O.Order_Date > '01/11/12' and O.Order_Date < '15/11/12'

Comment: In sqlite, there also function to get year, date and month for a DATE. month(O.Order_Date), year(O.Order_date)

Answer (score 2):

Try another format: YYYY-MM-DD

O.Order_Date between '2012-11-01' and '2012-11-15'

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

```
Time Strings

A time string can be in any of the following formats:

YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

Comment: Can you try this simple query: _SELECT Order_Date FROM T_Ohead WHERE Order_Date between '2012-11-01' and '2012-11-15' ORDER BY Order_Date_

Answer (score 0):

How to make it in YYYY/MM/DD from dd/MM/yy ((comment 2, answer 2))?

```
update tableName
set date =
'20' || substr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), '/')+1)
|| '/' ||
case when length(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1, instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1),'/')-1))=2
then substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1, instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), '/')-1)
else '0'||substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1, instr(substr(date, instr(date, '/')+1), '/')-1)
end
|| '/' ||
case when length(substr(date,1, instr(date, '/')-1 )) =2
then substr(date,1, instr(date, '/')-1 )
else '0'||substr(date,1, instr(date, '/')-1 )
end
```

Else look at the two last answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)