# SQLite varchar comparison as date

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two varchar field named StartDate(like `'MM/dd/yyyy'`) and StartTime(like '`hh:mm`').

> select * from Table "where StartDate<'MM/dd/yyyy'"

Can anybody help me with this query?

Comment: Could you be more specific please ? How could we help you ?

Comment: Actually I have a huge amount of data for StartDate and StartTime fields, which are VarChar (s). I need to select some of these row where StartDate< 'some Date'

Comment: Your question is probably already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates

Comment: Why, why, why do people store dates as Chars and not as Dates? Or at least with a decent Char format, like `YYYY-MM-DD` or  `YYYYMMDD`?

Comment: @ypercube, even I wonder the same thing...

Comment: @ManuelBarbe, Thanks I just tried that in sqlite admin and it worked. thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

For your specific problem you will have to convert the varchar yourself and the answer can be found in this stackoverflow post: [Sqlite convert string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428795/sqlite-convert-string-to-date)

sqlite would allow you to use a regular query for a date saved as a varchar - however, you will have to store the dates in the correct format - maybe you can change your date fields to follow this format? Have a look at the sqlite documentation: [sqlite date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).