# How to select if pass-in-Date is between DateRange

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I have a table which has DateTime fields as below:

```
 class ItemSales
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int SpId { get; set; }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ItemNo { get; set; }     
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal MinimumQuantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }       
        public decimal Cost { get; set; }      
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }

       ---- others
    }
```

---
others

The problem:

How to query where I need to check if the pass-in string date strCurrentDate (DateTime.Now)  is between StartDate and EndDate which are in the table?

If I pass in the current date as yyyy-mm-dd and I have the following function:

--- Update

error Message:

Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'

```
 private async void GetActualPrice(string Cpy, string No, string strCurrentDate,string strSelectedUoM)
 {
  var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);

var Items = await db.Table < ItemSales >().Where(x => x.CompanyName == Cpy && x.ItemNo == No && strCurrentDate > x.StarDate && strCurrentDate < x.EndDate).ToListAsync();



 foreach (var _line in Items)
 {

  }                 
}



No need to convert the Start and End Date into string ??? 

 "'" + strCurrentDate + "'" + " BETWEEN StartDate And EndDate");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Select between dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The difference is that I am passing in the date in string and I need to check against the dateTime fields in the table.

Comment: Have you read through the answers in the proposed duplicate question? Dates have to be specifically formatted in sqlite to be treated as dates since they are stored as strings in the DB.

Comment: I read it. For my case, the pass-in string date in format yyyy-mm-dd is used to check against the datetime fields as Compare to DateTime field check against string date format. I am testing it and not sure if this is workable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'current date', do you mean the time at which you submit the query to the database?  You can format the current date as a constant in the query, like :
Also, you need to provide a datatype for the query response, either by:

`List<String> Items = await db.QueryAsync( ...`

or

`var Items = await db.QueryAsync<List<String>>( ...`

then

```
    "Select * From ItemSales Where CompanyName ='" + Cpy + "' AND ItemNo ='" + No + "' AND '" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/M/d") + "' BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate");
```

Date will have form 2013/12/23.  I assume dates in your database are GMT.

(Edit: changed string.format() to string concatenation...)
(Edit: based on error message provided, C# needs to be told datatype returned by .QueryAsync().   There may also be a problem with SQL query syntax, but we won't find it till the datatype declaration is fixed.)

Comment: The Current date like : "2013-12-23"  How to check this against the dateTime fields in the table.

Comment: Can you write in the normal way without using the string.Format? It is strange that in the above format I use in select-statement, i have error in StartDate and EndDate even there are existed in the table. How to handle the Start And EndDates in Select-statement.

Comment: What is the specific error message you see?  It would also be useful to see the schema definition for the table, at least StartDate and EndDate columns, to be sure they are defined as SQL datetime.
I've edited my response above to remove string.Format() .

Comment: Ah- you need to declare a C# datatype for the value returned by QueryAsync since you did not declare it for Items.  Edited answer again

Comment: OK , I understand I need to add db.QueryAsync<itemSales> . I have question, do I need to convert the Start and End Date into string??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43796/discussion-between-bobhy-and-milkbottle)

Comment: (no chat)I do not think so. SQL can compare a string that is formatted like a date with a column that is declared to be datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite only compare dates when date are yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss formats. so when ever you insert datetime in sqlite db, insert in yyyy-MM-dd format as a string type for following query.

```
var Items = await db.QueryAsync("Select * From ItemSales Where CompanyName ='" + Cpy + "'" + " AND ItemNo ='" + No + "'" +
" AND " + "'" + strCurrentDate + "'" + " BETWEEN StartDate And EndDate");
```

Another way is you just simply use linq query for comparison of dates. here are the linq query

```
var Items = await db.Table<ItemSales>().Where(x=>x.CompanyName ==cpy && x.ItemNo ==No && x.strCurrentDate >StartDate && x.strCurrentDate <EndDate).ToList();
```

Comment: error Msg :Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Yes, the problem in LinQ. The Dates are inserted into the table as Date DataType (not using string).

Comment: @MilkBottle Convert  StartDate and EndDate as DateTime

Comment: Now my string Date is :strCurDate= "12/23/2013" and I use Convert.ToDateTime(strCurDate). Is date store in Table as Date? Error Msg: nosuch function todatetime.    var Items = await db.Table<ItemSalesPrice>().Where(x => x.CompanyName == Cpy && x.ItemNo == No && Convert.ToDateTime(strCurrentDate) >  x.StartingDate && Convert.ToDateTime(strCurrentDate) < x.EndingDate).ToListAsync();

Comment: Date is stored as DateTime in database. You could use DateTime.Parse(strCurDate) to convert from string to DateTime. E.g:                                                         
      DateTime dateValue;
      string dateString = "2/16/2020 12:15:12 PM";                                          
     dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString);