# Could not retrieve data from SQLite when using DateRange

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

This is strange. Why this is not working??
I have great difficulty in getting the data even thought I have searches which say to use this format :yyyy-mm-dd

Order_Date in tblSalesOrderHeader is normal DateTime .  I insert it like this : Order_Date = DateTime.Today in the SQLITE Insert operation.

How to handle this Order_Date in the SQL statement?

Would apprecaite your help.

```
Use the same table SalesOrderHeader 

The problem :

item(1) is working

Item(2) is not working using DateRange to retrieve records
Begin and End dates are converted in this string format : yyyy-mm-dd

I use this to convert the DateTime:

 private string DateTimeSQLite(DateTime datetime)
        {
            string dateTimeFormat = "{0}-{1}-{2}";

            return string.Format(dateTimeFormat, datetime.Year, datetime.Month, datetime.Day);
        }




//-- 1 : Working 

var query = db.Query<SalesOrderHeader>("Select * From SalesOrderHeader Where DataEntryComplete ='" + "0'" + " AND Is_SyncToNAV ='0" + "'");



//--2 : not working 

var query = db.Query <SalesOrderHeader>("Select * From SalesOrderHeader WHERE Order_Date BETWEEN '" + Begin +"'" + " AND '" + End +"'" + " AND DataEntryComplete ='" + "0'" + " AND Is_SyncToNAV ='0" + "'");
```

Comment: [You mean `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of `yyyy-mm-dd`, right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

Comment: Is there a difference? I really dont know. I use My own format converter as above.

Comment: At first, replace your `DateTimeSQLLite` with a simple `ToString` method: `datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` that results in `2014-02-15`. Does the error persist?

Comment: The problem is still the same.

Comment: I notice in SQLite DB, the DateTime format is : yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00. So I have to covert the Date into this format. I addedd 00:00:00 to the date format and it works. IS this the correct way ?

Comment: Good trial and error but seems weird to me since my first comment references that yyyy-MM-dd should sulfide
. Anyway, the `ToString()` call should be `datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'DateTime.ToShortDateString()' will fetch you date string in yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: Format from M.Mimpen is correct and I believe yours is the same. My question is the Time part (00:00:00). As your method will not return this way yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00  .and my question is if I add this time part , will this be the correct way.

Comment: Can you change the format of 'Order_Date' while executing query, something like this. "select * from salesorderheader where order_date.toshortdatestring() between begin.toshortdatestring() and end.toshortdatestring()

Comment: You have to change the format of all the datetime objects while executing them to a common format , so that all datetime objects are in same format.