# Android and SQLite - select datetime error

Tags: android

How can I select everything from an Android SQLite database a day?

I have created the following table:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "" +
        "create table " + TABLE_STATISTIC + " (" 
          + COLUMN_STATISTIC_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
          + COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME + " DATETIME , "
          + COLUMN_STATISTIC_SERVICED + " integer not null, "
          + COLUMN_STATISTIC_CATEGORY + " integer); ";
```

Then I select

```
"Select * from " + TABLE_STATISTIC + " where " + COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME + " > " + startTime " AND " COLUMN_STATISTIC_DATETIME + " < " + endTime + ";"
```

But this as query doesn't work fine in my case, sqlite don't show any error but no output in this case help me to get

Thank all

Comment: Probably because your date format has issue, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates

Comment: Make sure your dates (in bd and also in comparison parameters) are correct **Time String**s.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates?lq=1 Please check this and print your strings in Log

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this example

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND tbl_name = 'COMPANY';
```

For More [See Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_select_query.htm)

Comment: I select for Datetime

Comment: this is example  you can modify by your need. you also can use LIKE %something% for this. @longle