# Select between dates SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to write a query in my Java program to select records between two dates. I have built my dates as such:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date parsed;
try 
{
    parsed = formatter.parse(sqlDateIn);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
    returnDate = sqlDate;
}
```

When I query the DB I get the attached.

I cannot get the query to select any records (e.g. between 01/01/15 and 12/31/15).  I have tried all sorts of combos of `strftime`, but to no avail.

I am a noob to Java and SQLite, so I am sure it is a dumb user error.

[image: Image of database table]

Sorry about my reply below.

```
SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE DateSort BETWEEN '01/01/15' AND '12/31/15'

SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE DateSort BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2015/12/31' 

SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE DateSort BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' 

SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL strftime('%m/%d/%Y', DateSort) BETWEEN '01/01/15' AND '12/31/15'
```

Above is what I have tried in Firefox SQLite Manager extension.

EDIT:
In the above, I had DateSort defined as DATETIME.  I have changed to DATE and VARCHAR and run the above queries, nothing selected.

I have also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE date(DateSort) BETWEEN date('01/01/15') AND date('12/31/15')

SELECT * FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE date(DateSort) BETWEEN date('2015-01-01') AND date('2015-12-31')
```

Neither worked.  Don't know what else to try.

EDIT:

I grabbed this small piece of code and modified it to test.  It does not work.  What am I missing?

```
public class SQLiteTest 
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/Users/peterream/Desktop/Desktop Archive/Crashplan/sqlitetest.sqlite");
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists people;");
            stat.executeUpdate("create table people (name TEXT, occupation TEXT, DateSort INTEGER);");
            PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(
                "insert into people values (?, ?, ?);");

            prep.setString(1, "Gandhi");
            prep.setString(2, "politics");
            prep.setDate(3, convertSQLDate("2016-04-08"));
            prep.addBatch();
            prep.setString(1, "Turing");
            prep.setString(2, "computers");
            prep.setDate(3, convertSQLDate("2015-04-08"));
            prep.addBatch();
            prep.setString(1, "Wittgenstein");
            prep.setString(2, "smartypants");
            prep.setDate(3, convertSQLDate("2014-04-08"));
            prep.addBatch();

            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            prep.executeBatch();
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);

            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from people WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', DateSort) BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31';");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
                System.out.println("job = " + rs.getString("occupation"));
                System.out.println("DateSort = " + rs.getString("DateSort"));
            }
            rs.close();
            conn.close();
        }
/**
**
* This method converts input string date to sql date format
* 
* @param  String sqlDateIn (MM/dd/yy)
* @return java.sql.Date returnDate
*/

        public static java.sql.Date convertSQLDate (String sqlDateIn)
        {
            java.sql.Date returnDate = null;

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
            java.util.Date parsed;
            try 
            {
                parsed = formatter.parse(sqlDateIn);
                java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
                returnDate = sqlDate;
            }
            catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return returnDate;
        }
}
```

I am looking to select 1 row 2015-04-08.

Comment: can you add your query that you are using in java?

Comment: also your date format should be `YYYY-MM-DD`. check this for info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates

Comment: I gave up trying it in my program and tried the queries in Firefox SQLite Manager extension.  I tried the following: SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE DateSort BETWEEN '01/01/15' AND '12/31/15'

SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE DateSort BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2015/12/31' 

SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL WHERE DateSort BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31' 

SELECT Course, date  DateSort FROM Peter_SCORE_TBL strftime('%m/%d/%Y', DateSort) BETWEEN '01/01/15' AND '12/31/15'    This last one didn't pass syntax.  Sorry about form

Comment: What is the format of the date values in the table?

Comment: DATETIME would be `'2015-01-01T00:00'` though I thought `'2015-01-01'` should work too. That `date DateSort` is a bit extraordinary but seems unproblematic. (Not much experienct with SQLite)

Comment: Tried 2015-01-01T00:00, did not work.

Comment: SQLite does not have a `DATETIME` column type; see [Datatypes](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). You need to make sure the data in your tables is consistent in order to order them. Use the [date functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) when inserting data.

Comment: I have changed my DateSort field to INTEGER.  I add data with same date function above in my original.  Same result, no selected data.

Comment: For some reason, I thought to store the date in SQLite, I had to convert the date to a sqlDate.  That appears to be what is messing me up.  If I leave the date as a string ("yyyy-mm-dd"), all works fine.