# Query between dates in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to query what happened between today and yesterday. To example on the 17th of June 2016 it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM Inspection_Log WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2016-6-16' AND '2016-6-17'
```

But these days are relative, and this won't work say tomorrow, or really every again. So I've encountered [this](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) page where tells me now to use `DATE` as it's just a polite wrapper around `strftime`.

But here is my current issue:

This query works:

```
>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inspection_Log WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2016-6-16' AND '2016-6-17'
535
```

But when I use `date('yada', '+1 day')`

```
>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inspection_LOG WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2016-6-16' AND DATE('2016-6-16','+1 day')
0
```

So I try with  `strftime`

```
>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inspection_LOG WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2016-6-16' AND strftime('%Y-%M-%D','2016-6-16','+1 day')
0
```

So I try with  `datetime`

```
>SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inspection_LOG WHERE date_time BETWEEN '2016-6-16' AND datetime('2016-6-16','+1 day')
0
```

Digging into this here is what i see
    SELECT time('now')
    '2016-06-24'
    SELECT date('now')
    '2016-06-24'
    SELECT date('now','-1 day')
    '2016-06-23'
    SELECT date('2016-6-24','-1 day')
    NONE

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change: AND strftime('%Y-**%M-%D**','2016-**6**-16','+1 day') for AND strftime('%Y-**%m-%d**','2016-**06**-16','+1 day').

1 - You should use '%Y-%m-%d' for the first parameter  'YYYY-MM-DD'. 
The format string supports the most common substitutions found in the strftime() function from the standard C library plus two new substitutions, %f and %J.  [The complete list link](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

2 -  A time string must be follow the format: YYYY-MM-DD, then you need to use '2016-06-16'.

There is a question and answer : [SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

Comment: I inserted data incorrect initially so I was querying `TEXT` field's as `DATE` fields which gave no results. Even tho the column was declared as `DATE`... this is really `TEXT` as far as sqlite3 is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was totally and completely wrong.

My scheme looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE InspectionLog(
    date_time DATE, 
    station_name TEXT,
    inspection TEXT,
    barcode_part_number TEXT,
    bus_part_number TEXT,
    barcode_serial_number TEXT,
    bus_serial_number TEXT,
    rework_operation TEXT,
    status TEXT,
    ng_description TEXT
 )
```

`DATE` is not a valid data type. It is actually a high level wrapper around `INTEGER` and `TEXT` depending on the data placed into it. Sqlite3 defaults to `TEXT`.

What this means is when I perform an insert/update which does something similar to:

```
  date_time = '2016-6-16'
```

This is valid as `date_time` is really `TEXT` not `DATE`. And when I preform a search that uses the `DATE` data type, it will skip any row which isn't a `DATE`.

The long version is. I inserted ~250MB incorrectly formatted into this table. After fixing my tests and functions so my inserts always have 2 day/month digits the majority of the OP's time queries work correctly.