# QDateTime with sqlite3

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm using Sqlite3 with Qt , anyway to save the DateTime form in the db i used Text type , see this from my db :
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf1ZC.jpg)

so the INSERT and SELECT is work very , but how i could make specific SELECT !

my code :

```
QString("SELECT * from main.sell_cash_log WHERE 'when' >= '%1' AND 'when' <= '%2'").arg(ui->fromdate->dateTime().toString("dd-MM-yyyy:HH-mm-ss")).arg(ui->todate->dateTime().toString("dd-MM-yyyy:HH-mm-ss"))
```

Comment: Do you want your query to select information on a specific date?

Comment: Can you write what you want to get and what you are getting?

Comment: @Marco select rows from db , where the date in rows is betwwen date i select ( fromdate - todate )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was by the field called when , in insert query i was useing escape string ('when') but with select not work (' ' ) so i used (`when`) and it's workd :
:

```
CartItems->setQuery(QString("SELECT * from main.sell_cash_log WHERE datetime(`when`) BETWEEN datetime('%1') AND datetime('%2')").arg(ui->fromdate->dateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")).arg(ui->todate->dateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using one of the date operaterators to get info for a specific date

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_data_types.htm

To select all in the month of November:

`SELECT * FROM main.sell_cash_log WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', when) BETWEEN "11-01-2016" AND "11-31-2016"`

See also [SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates) which is where I copied that query q

Comment: i used:  `CartItems->setQuery(QString("SELECT * from main.sell_cash_log WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','when') BETWEEN '%1' AND '%2'").arg(ui->fromdate->dateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")).arg(ui->todate->dateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")));`
but it still not work , note I'm using `QSqlQueryModel` for this query and QTableView to view the query

Comment: I've also tried
`CartItems->setQuery(QString("SELECT * from main.sell_cash_log WHERE date('when') BETWEEN date('%1') AND date('%2')").arg(ui->fromdate->dateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")).arg(ui->todate->dateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")));`

Comment: can you verify that the string outputs from your dates look right?

Comment: [img](http://image.prntscr.com/image/5d20d5ac26ac40b5bf6f7659bcd36a88.png) that is my db data ,
and that is the qdebug for the query : `"SELECT * from main.sell_cash_log WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S','when') BETWEEN '2015-11-0900:00:00' AND '2016-11-0900:00:00'"`

Comment: You need a space between the hour and the day.   `'2015-11-0900:00:00'` should be `'2015-11-09 00:00:00'`

Comment: oh yes sry i only was testing it without space , this with space `"SELECT * from main.sell_cash_log WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S','when') BETWEEN '2015-11-09 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-09 00:00:00'"` and same problem

Comment: Ok, those two dates are the same,  there is nothing between '2015-11-09 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-09 00:00:00'     you'd need to change one to be a different day like '2015-11-09 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-10 00:00:00'

Comment: no not the same , one is on 2015 year and the other is on 2016 !