# SQLite - no data sqlite select with condition on datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, sqlite

I have select query in SQLite Database. There is a LogInTime field that datatime datatype.

Here is `AccessDate` variable passing date `"11/16/2016"` like format

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Tble_Login where LogInTime = '" + AccessDate + "'";
```

The SQLite Tble_Login looking like this,

[image]

After excute this query, no data? How can I get data?

Comment: There is no `datatime` datatype in SQLite, that is a `text`: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @Aidin Ya its my mistake correct image i have added. I have also use datetime(...) in query but still it return null value

Comment: I assume you use this `sql` as a command in somewhere, it would be better to use prepared (parameterized) statements instead of string concatenation. This kind of siuations are open for SQL Injection attacsk.

Comment: @SonerGönül . I will follow as you say

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [SQLite documentaion](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you should use following format for `AccessDate`
`YYYY-MM-DD`or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` or `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. On the documentation page you can find more formats in the section *Time Strings*
You can also try to use the `BETWEEN` statement like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)
`string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Tble_Login where LogInTime BETWEEN ""2016-11-16"" AND ""2016-11-17""";`