# unable to get next 7 days data from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, intervals

I am creating reminder application and in which I am adding reminder details in SQLite. I am adding date as a string in `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format. But when I am trying to get next 7 days data then I am getting following exception.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.sandy.remindcall, PID: 31982
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "11": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM call_reminder WHERE reminder_date_time BETWEEN 21/05/2017 11:49:19 AND 14/05/2017 11:49:19
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
```

Here is my code.

```
public Cursor getNextSevenDaysRecord(){
    Calendar theEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar theStart = (Calendar) theEnd.clone();

    theStart.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +7);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MM_SS);
    String start = dateFormat.format(theStart.getTime());
    String end = dateFormat.format(theEnd.getTime());

    // Now you have date boundaries in TEXT format
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE "+KEY_DATE_TIME+" BETWEEN "+start+" AND "+end,null);

    return cursor;
}
```

Please give me any reference

Comment: Since SQLite does not have a date and time datatype, how did you define the column in the table?

Comment: KEY_DATE_TIME is nothing but String. I am saving date ins String format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: use SQLite - Date & Time or you can't query like that using `between`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by not quoting the string values in the SQL statement. But even after quoting it would not work correctly, because the values would be compared as strings and not as dates, so 14/05/2017 would be before 19/05/2015 in lexical order.

To fix this either store the dates as number or use a format whith the year in front, then month, then day.