# I can't change my query into a parametized query with like

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I know a lot of questions exists about this topic. But i tried everything and nothing worked. As I mentioned in the title, i'm trying to change my unsafe query into a safer one.

I think the problem are the points. My goal is to insert the month and the year into the query. And both should be separated by points.

Just something like this: " **.08.2017** "

**The old query which worked**

```
string Query = @"select id from ferien WHERE Datum LIKE '%." + monat + "." + jahr + "'";
```

**The new query which doesn't work**

```
String Query = @"select id from ferien WHERE Datum LIKE '%. @monat . @jahr'";
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlite_conn))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@monat", monat);
                command.Parameters.Add("@jahr", jahr);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I'm using a sqlite db.

I'm thankful for any advice or solution.

**Edit**

It doesn't give me any errors. While debugging it runs trough like normal. It just acts like it found nothing in the db.

Comment: You have spaces in the new query that are not there in the old query.

Comment: Do you mean the ones between the points and the "variables" ? It also doesn't work if I delete the spaces.

Comment: you need to be concatenating strings; in your query you are simply creating a string with `@monat` and `@jahr` in it (literally); please take the time to read the docs and learn how these things work before posting questions

Comment: what is the datatype of the `Datum`?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu I know it's not the best solution. But I'm using my Datum as a varchar...

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama Like I said, I tried a lot of things. Including the way of writing mentioned in the docs. But nothing worked...

Comment: so you've tried this: `'%.' + @monat + '.' + @jahr + ''''` ?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama Yeah, something like this.

Comment: Strange how I get a devote every time. Can I change something in the way of asking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixing your current approach:**

You'd have to *concat* the parameter with the fixed part of the query, so depending on your database, it would be something like

```
select id from ferien WHERE Datum LIKE '%.' || @monat || '.' || @jahr
```

or

```
select id from ferien WHERE Datum LIKE CONCAT('%.', @monat, '.', @jahr)
```

I think the first one using the common `||` SQL concatenation operator works in SQLite as well. *Note that the common `+` operator typically doesn't work for string concatenation in SQL.*

The whole code would become

```
String Query = @"select id from ferien WHERE Datum LIKE '%' || @monat || '.' || @jahr";
using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlite_conn))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@monat", monat);
    command.Parameters.Add("@jahr", jahr);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**(Better?) `between`:**

That aside, it would be even better if you have an actual date in your database, and you would use that in your query, so it would look like:

```
select id from ferien WHERE Datum BETWEEN "2017-08-01" AND "2017-09-01"
```

See also [SQLite: SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the parameters in the right way, they have to be a single value and cannot be used as string replacements (like you're doing). So use this instead

```
String Query = @"select id from ferien WHERE Datum LIKE @date";
            using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlite_conn))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@date", $".{monat}.{jahr}");                   
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```