# Pdo - Data between two dates

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

I am writing a portable web application with Php and I am using SQLite for my database. I want to  display the date difference between two dates but it isn't working at the moment.
Can you help me, please?
(My English is not good, sorry).

My Code:

```
<h3>Tarihe göre arama</h3>

    <form class="form-horizontal"  action="" method="post">                     
        <label>Tarih 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tarih1" id="tarih1" value="<?php echo $buguntarih;?>" required>

        <label>Tarih 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tarih2" id="tarih2" value="<?php echo $buguntarih;?>" required>

            <input type="submit"  value="Filtrele" name="filtrele" class="btn btn-primary  pull-right" style="background:none;">                                                        
    </form>

<?php 
    if($_POST['filtrele']){
        $tarih1=$_POST['tarih1'];
        $tarih2=$_POST['tarih2'];

        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  islem where eklenme_tarihi between '{$tarih1}' and '{$tarih2}' and sirket_id={$sirketid} order by id ", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else{
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM  islem where sirket_id={$sirketid} order by id ", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }                                   
?>
<?php echo $sirket['sirket_adi']; ?></b> şirketine ait işlemler (

    <?php 

    if($_POST['filtrele']){ 
        echo "<b>".$tarih1."</b> ve <b>".$tarih2."</b> arası"; 
    } else{
        echo"tümü";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Please describe the problem AND any error messages with your current code

Comment: Use **SQL BETWEEN** that might help you out

Comment: @BaranselA. I am fairly sure the OP is doing just that, if you look a little closer

Comment: Your problem is possibly the format that the user enters the data into the form. It must be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format when you use it in the query. If the user is entering anything else you need to convert it to that format

Comment: Is `eklenme_tarihi` stored as a `DATE` in the database? Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @lufc SQLite doesn't have strict data types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

Comment: `echo $sirket['sirket_adi'];` that doesn't do anything really, except throw an error about an undefined variable.

Comment: just as a html note- `<strong>` should be used instead of `<b>`

Comment: *Error Code (When i try SQL Between):
"Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp....."

*In my date format has not problem. Because ı can show data from eklenme_tarihi / database. I can not show data between two dates. 

*eklenme_tarihi is date format in my database. 

*Users enters the data into the form is not important. I wanna show to data between two dates.