# SQL: Sum based on specified dates

Tags: sqlite

Thanks again for the help everyone. I went with the script below...

```
SELECT beginning, end, 
(SELECT SUM(sale) FROM sales_log WHERE date BETWEEN beginning AND `end` ) AS sales 
FROM performance
```

and I added a salesperson column to both the performance table and sales_log but it winds up crashing DB Browser. What is the issue here? New code below:

```
SELECT beginning, end, salesperson
(SELECT SUM(sale) FROM sales_log WHERE (date BETWEEN beginning AND end) AND sales_log.salesperson = performance.salesperson ) AS sales 
FROM performance
```

Comment: The 1/3 to 18 sum should be $15, I reckon.  Your sample data might have a problem.  Have you tried to write a query yet?

Comment: please use Quote or code formatting to segregate data or code or simple text. Also please add more detail and what have you done so far. Welcome to StckOverflow

Comment: Made edits, apologies for formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Select between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187288/sql-select-between-dates)

Comment: First change the format of your dates to YYYY-MM-DD if you want to apply the operator BETWEEN, or do any comparison with dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following may do what you wish or be the basis for what you wish.

```
WITH sales_log_cte AS 
    (
        SELECT substr(date,(length(date) -3),4)||'-'||
            CASE WHEN length(replace(substr(date,instr(date,'/')+1,2),'/','')) < 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END
                ||replace(substr(date,instr(date,'/')+1,2),'/','')||'-'||
            CASE WHEN length(substr(date,1,instr(date,'/') -1)) < 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END||substr(date,1,instr(date,'/') -1) AS date,
            CAST(sale AS REAL) AS sale
        FROM sales_log
    ),
    performance_cte AS 
        (
            SELECT substr(beginning,(length(beginning) -3),4)||'-'||
                CASE WHEN length(replace(substr(beginning,instr(beginning,'/')+1,2),'/','')) < 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END
                    ||replace(substr(beginning,instr(beginning,'/')+1,2),'/','')||'-'||
                CASE WHEN length(substr(beginning,1,instr(beginning,'/') -1)) < 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END||substr(beginning,1,instr(beginning,'/') -1)
                AS beginning,

                substr(`end`,(length(`end`) -3),4)||'-'||
                CASE WHEN length(replace(substr(`end`,instr(`end`,'/')+1,2),'/','')) < 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END
                    ||replace(substr(`end`,instr(`end`,'/')+1,2),'/','')||'-'||
                CASE WHEN length(substr(`end`,1,instr(`end`,'/') -1)) < 2 THEN '0' ELSE '' END||substr(`end`,1,instr(`end`,'/') -1)
                AS `end`

            FROM performance
        )

SELECT beginning, `end` , (SELECT SUM(sale) FROM sales_log_cte WHERE date BETWEEN beginning AND `end` ) AS sales
FROM performance_cte
;
```

From your data this results in :-

[image]

As can be seen the bulk of the code is converting the dates into a format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) that is usable/recognisable by SQLite for the BETWEEN clause.

- [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

I don't believe that you want a join between performance (preformance_cte after reformatting the dates) and sales_log (sales_log_cte) as this will be a cartesian product and then sum will sum all the results within the range.

The use of **end** as a column name is also awkward as it is a KEYWORD requiring it to be enclosed (**`** grave accents used in the above).

The above works by using 2 CTE's (Common Table Expresssions), which are temporary tables who'd life time is for the query in which they are used.

The first **sales_log_cte** is simply the sales_log table but with the date reformatted. The second, likewise, is simply the performace table with the dates reformatted.

If the tables already has suitable date formatting then all of the above could simply be :-

```
SELECT beginning, `end` , (SELECT SUM(sale) FROM sales_log WHERE date BETWEEN beginning AND `end` ) AS sales FROM performance;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. And thank you so much for thoroughly explaining it to a beginner!

Comment: @yuujia if the answer helped then please click the tick mark to show that the question as been answered.